# prevent flask reload on change

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pycharm

I am trying to code in pycharm in debug mode and as I am trying to work out a problem I am typing in the file I am working in.  I am referencing current code in the debug console so I need that to stay.  Unfortunately once I start typing code, flask reloads and I lose my debug console.
 Is there any way to prevent flask from reloading?
If I want it to reload I will restart the app manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if you have `app.run(use_reloader=True)`. Even if not, put this param and make it `False`.